# ubuntu smttp sendmail not working

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I am trying to sendmail from ubuntu and I get this error:

> sendmail: Authorization failed (454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. x45sm29101395eeu.23 - gsmtp)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occured on my machine as long as I had "AuthUser=username@gmail.com" in my ssmtp.conf. After replacing "username" with the first part of my e-mail address, the problem disappeared and ssmtp sent the message.
Cheers,
0nickyet

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary problem. It happens when the server that checks your credentials dont do the check locally, instead they use another authentication server and the connection to this server failure causes the 454 error

If the credential's were incorrect, we would get 535 error

Wait for some time, and try again and if you have an auto system,put in a loop upto 3 attempts.